# How to generate a random, relatively prime number to p?

Tags: random, prime-numbers

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question, but I'm a newbie and googling didn't help me much.

Is there a way in Mathematica to generate a number `q` coprime with `p` without resorting to do it "by hand" by iterating over a list of random numbers and using `CoprimeQ`?

I see how the likelihood of hitting a coprime soon is pretty good, but I wonder if there is a *cleaner*, or, if you want, more Mathematica-like way to do it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: just FYI the brute force approach `(While[ ! CoprimeQ[n , i = RandomInteger[n]]]; i)` is much faster than the "more elegant" answers..

Comment: @george2079 hey, I like more elegant answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a straightforward function generating a random coprime number less than given natural number `x`.

```
cpr[x_Integer]/; x > 1 := 
  RandomChoice @ Pick[ Range[x], CoprimeQ[ x, Range[x]]]
```

e.g.

```
cpr[341]
```

> ```
> 79
> ```

However if we are to deal with larger numbers the given definition is not very convenient therfore it is reasonable to provide another definition yielding a random coprime between `k` and `m` e.g.

```
cpr[x_Integer, k_Integer, m_Integer] /; x > m > k > 1 := 
  RandomChoice @ Pick[ Range[k, m], CoprimeQ[ x, Range[k, m]]]
```

for a choice between `k` and `m`

e.g.

```
cpr[32059725, 21172781, 25565647]
```

> ```
> 21921206
> ```

If one chooses an appropriate range there are always some coprimes unless `k` and `m` are too close.

Comment: I believe this is a solution that the OP has specifically excluded in their question. Better if we can do it without having to generate a list of candidates and only after that verify whether they are coprime or not.

Comment: @OleksandrR.  The provided solution is quite good and very Mathematica-like one. The OP as a newbie excludes iterating over a list of random numbers and then using `CoprimeQ`. There is no iteration, no random list, just a range of numbers and simply `CoprimeQ` for which there is no better substitution. Just a reliable solution, if you can see a better one, clarify what you mean. I guess you might have suggested another mathematical approach if it had existed but I susspect it hadn't.  Unless you find the solution by rcollyer better, however frankly I don't.

Answer (score 3):

Using the definition of [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers), it is straightforward to construct a function that will do as you ask.

```
Clear[randomCoprime];
randomCoprime[n_Integer, k_Integer : Automatic] :=
Block[{count, maxP, factors, allowedF},
  maxP = PrimePi@Sqrt@n;
  factors = PrimePi@FactorInteger[n][[All,1]];
  count = If[k===Automatic, RandomInteger[{2, maxP}], k];
  allowedF = Complement[Range[2,maxP], factors];
  Times@@Prime[RandomChoice[allowedF, count]]
]
```

It works by indexing the prime factors of `n` via `PrimePi`, generating a list of allowed prime indices, and then randomly choosing from that list. The final number is reconstructed using `Prime`.  In the function, `k` determines the number of coprime factors chosen, and it will be randomly determined, if not specified.